# Android dumpsys batterystats

Tags: android, adb

I run `adb shell dumpsys batterystats` and I trying to understand what is the meaning ofthe following output:
Note: myservice - is wakeful service

```
Service com.myapp.myservice:
Created for: 20m 9s 632ms uptime
Starts: 87, launches: 87
```

Is that the time that takes to myservice to run?

Comment: `uptime` <- pretty sure that's the time it's been running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did some testing on this one.

**Created for =** the TOTAL amount of time it has been running since device booted, even if the service was stopped.

**Starts =** how many times the service has been started in background since last boot

**Launches =** how many times the service was launched from an Intent since last boot

I learned something today, Hope this helps!